# How can someone determine where a wireless router/SSID originated?

Tags: wireless

Someone hacked my wifi. I beefed up security. They now have renamed their SSID with a derogatory SSID including my apartment number. I want to find where they are so I can confront them. Is that possible?

Comment: "They hacked my WiFi" has nothing to do with them changing the SSID.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Android smartphone or tablet, you can use the WiFi Analyzer app. It has a screen dedicated to detecting the proximity of access points.

[image]

Walk around and see where the signal is the strongest.